# Error : Cannot convert value of type 'String.Type' to expected dictionary key type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

The following is my code where in the last line of the code I am getting an error as mentioned in the title. what should i do??

```
let jsonObject: [Any]  = [
    [
        "userName": "meUser",
        "emailID": "meUser@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "7290407896",
        "fiatCurrency": ["currencyCode" : "INR"],
        "countryCode": "IND",
    ]
]

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
print(jsonString)
User.saveUser(userData: [String: (jsonString)!])
```

Comment: What's up with the `String` dictionary key on the last line? `String` is a type, not a value to be used as a dictionary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. You are using a Swift **Type** `String` instead of an **instance** of `String` to store your value `jsonString`.

You should be using a `String` key which you will use later to retrieve your value.

```
if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
    User.saveUser(userData: ["jsonString": jsonString])
}
```

**Note:** Use `String` instead of `NSString` in Swift (the same method is available for `String`) and safely unwrap your `jsonString`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

> User.saveUser(userData: [String: (jsonString)!])

Here, you have provided `dictionary key = String`, `String` is a type in Swift, you can't use it as key for dictionary. You need to provide a value which is of type `String` not `String` itself.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is **Struct** type in swift which is used in the last line,

```
User.saveUser(userData: [String: (jsonString)!])
```

Use some string object rather than class name. Such as:

```
User.saveUser(userData: ["your_key_name": (jsonString)!])
```

And you can updated your code as:

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted)
if let json = jsonData, let jsonString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)
    User.saveUser(userData: ["key_name": jsonString])
}
```

Comment: [String in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) is actually a structure (`struct`) type. Either way, it would be sufficient in that first sentence to say that "String is a type".

Comment: Thanks @DavidRönnqvist for highlight, will update my answer.